Are there any NPCs related to House Dres in Morrowind?
In Elder Scrolls lore, around the in-universe timeline of the Elder Scrolls III: Morrowind, there were the six great dunmer houses, House Redoran, House Telvanni, House Hlaalu, House Dres, House Indoril and House Dagoth.
The first three feature quite prominently in the game, and the last is the primary group of antagonists of the main quest. House Indoril is at least indirectly relevant via the Ordinators as well as the fact that "you" are supposed to be the reincarnation of an ancient Indoril hero, Nerevar.
But House Dres, despite being one of the Great Houses at the time, doesn't seem to appear anywhere. I'm not expecting anything major like an actual plotline or anything, or a big faction building, but I wanted to know if House Dres turn up at all.
Are there any NPCs relating to House Dres in the Elder Scroll III: Morrowind?

I am not aware of any NPCs connected to House Dres in either the Morrowind base game or its expansions. The reason for this is that Elder Scrolls 3: Morrowind does not include the whole of Morrowind Province in its geographic area - it only includes the island of Vvardenfell. Only 3 of the 5 great Dunmer houses (if we exclude Dagoth) are active on Vvardenfell: Hlaalu, Redoran and Telvanni. So, houses Dres and Indoril don't really feature much. Even though House Dres does not officially have any holdings on Vvardenfell, you would think the player might encounter some visitors/travellers from House Dres; however, again I am not aware of any official NPCs. Development of the original game was somewhat rushed and they probably had their hands full with the 3 houses that feature more prominently.
This Elder Scrolls Wiki page shows some House Dres NPCs from Elder Scrolls Online and Elder Scrolls: Legends; however, it doesn't depict or reference any from Morrowind. The same page gives a list of in-game books that reference House Dres (incl. Great Houses of Morrowind, A Game at Dinner), and that is probably the closest you will get to them in ES3.
It's worth noting that the Tamriel Rebuilt mod is aiming to expand the geographic area of the game to include the mainland part of Morrowind Province. They have added a very impressive amount of additional territory so far; however, they have not yet added the very South-Eastern part of the mainland province, which is where House Dres is based. That region is one of the last they are planning to do, so even there we are going to have to wait a while until we see much representation of House Dres in Tamriel Rebuilt. You can see from the page I linked that Tamriel Rebuilt have included 5 House Dres NPCs, in Port Telvannis and Necrom, although they haven't added any in Vvardenfell. It's possible that might change, once they start fleshing out the South-East region and House Dres some more.
House Indoril, on the other hand, are very well represented in Tamriel Rebuilt. Their main regions are for the most part completed, including several of their settlements. They have a bunch of side quests and I believe it is possible to join them (although, if I remember correctly, it requires marrying one of their nobles).
